# Does Facebook foward my conversion pixel to its corresponding ad service?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, ads

Just a simple question here -- if I use The Facebook SDK to register an ad conversion (iOS app install, eg) will facebook then in turn *forward that information* on to my ad service?

Or am I required to also include the ad service's sdk to register the conversion separately?

Answer (score 1):

You mean that do you should add any code to get conversion results? I think yes, because you may want to measure not only installs conversion, but also in-app purchasing or other app section progress..

So for log that your app achieve some action (like install for example) you should use

```
[FBInsights logConversionPixel:<pixelID> valueOfPixel:0]
```

Where  you can get where create conversion pixel on Conversion Tracking section of Ads Manager.

Also don't forget set app client token in FBSettings class before log it:

```
[FBSettings setClientToken:@"<your app client token>"];
```

You can get client token on your app settings page - Advanced - Security section. There should be checkpoint "Client token" that set to OFF. Just set it ON and save changes, then you get client token

Please, correct me if I wrong, because there is no a lot of documentation about Facebook conversion tool for mobile app...